# Letter Count with Frequency, using Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, count, frequency, letter

I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

How do I get this code to record ONLY the frequency of letters in a text file into a dictionary (does NOT count spaces, line, numbers, etc)?

Additionally how do I divide each letter by the total letters to report the percent frequency of each letter in the file?

This is what I have currently:

```
def linguisticCalc():
    """
    Asks user to input a VALID filename. File must be a text file. IF valid, returns the frequency of ONLY letters in file.

    """
    filename = input("Please type your VALID filename")
    if os.path.exists(filename) == True:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            f_content = f.read()
            freq = {}
            for i in f_content:
                if i in freq:
                    freq[i] += 1
                else:
                    freq[i] = 1
        print(str(freq))

    else:
        print("This filename is NOT valid. Use the getValidFilename function to test inputs.")
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are on a wrong site if you are looking us to work on your assignment that you produced zero effort into solving. We help correcting code.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help you determine whether the character in question is a letter, is this:

```py
import string

# code here

if character in string.ascii_letters:
    # code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

You can use it to Count every letter in a string:

```
Counter('Articles containing potentially dated statements from 2011')
```

It gives this output, which is useful for counting characters in a string:

> Counter({'A': 1,
>            'r': 2,
>            't': 8,
>            'i': 4,
>            'c': 2,
>            'l': 3,
>            'e': 5,
>            's': 3,
>            ' ': 6,
>            'o': 3,
>            'n': 5,
>            'a': 4,
>            'g': 1,
>            'p': 1,
>            'y': 1,
>            'd': 2,
>            'm': 2,
>            'f': 1,
>            '2': 1,
>            '0': 1,
>            '1': 2})

Comment: I tried this, but it records the spaces, numbers, etc. I need something that records ONLY letters.